# php POST method error while submitting

Tags: php

Im trying to submit a form from one php to another. But it gives me error. Please help

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label class = "log3"> Username</label>
                <input class = "log" type="text" id="user" name="studentid">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label class = "log4"> Password </label>
                <input class = "log2" type="password" id="pass" name="Pass">
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="studentbtn" value="As Student">
                <input type="submit" id="lecturerbtn" value="As Lecturer">
            </p>
        </form>
```

**Here is the php file which gets the submitted values**

```
$lecturerid = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

Error Message :

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coursework\script.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coursework\script.php on line 5.

Comment: What's the error you talking about ?

Comment: Probably the fact that the name of his inputs don't match the ones in his `$_POST` variables

Comment: use name instead of id

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coursework\script.php on line 4
___________________________
Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coursework\script.php on line 5.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `name` instead of `id`

The `name` attribute is used when sending data in a form submission. You may have several radio buttons with different `id` attributes, but the same `name`. When submitted, there is just the one value in the response - the radio button you selected.

For your form:

```
    <form action="script.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label class = "log3"> Username</label>
            <input class = "log" type="text" id="user" name="studentid">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label class = "log4"> Password </label>
            <input class = "log2" type="password" id="pass" name="Pass">
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="studentbtn" value="As Student">
            <input type="submit" id="lecturerbtn" value="As Lecturer">
        </p>
    </form>


$lecturerid = $_POST['studentid'];
$password = $_POST['Pass'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for the `name` attribute of the input in the `$_POST` variable :

```
$lecturerid = $_POST['studentid'];
$password = $_POST['Pass'];
```

Follow this link for the php manual tutorial : http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Should be `Pass`instead of `pass`can't edit since that's only one character of editing.

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for validate the answer if it solved your question. Good luck @Java_NewBie

Answer (score 0):

```
$lecturerid = $_POST['studentid'];
$password = $_POST['Pass'];
```

Use name attribute instead of id.

Comment: please explain a bit more why the user should use `name` attributes instead of `id`

Comment: In Html Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

Your form inputs name are studentid and Pass

```
 <input class = "log" type="text" id="user" name="studentid">
 <input class = "log2" type="password" id="pass" name="Pass">
```

therefor your $_POST[''] methods are should  like  bellow

```
$lecturerid = $_POST['studentid'];
$password = $_POST['Pass'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you have done is instead of using the name you have used the id which is wrong since if you want to call something using the POST Super variable on another page u need to call with its 'name' that you have given in the previous page.

```
 <input class = "log" type="text" id="user" name="studentid">
```

In the above code the name you given is 'studentid' therefore when you are trying to access the data entered in this you need to do as below.

```
$lecturerid = $_POST['studentid'];
```

For further reference please check out https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php